# Validar punto en correo java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente objetivo:

Validar que un correo ingresado por un JOptionPane.showInputDialog, contenga un arroba (@) y un punto (.), si no cumple con estos parámetros, indicar que es un correo incorrecto y en caso contrario, correo correcto.

Estoy iniciando en java y no tengo conocimiento del porque, al momento de validar el punto no me arroja la respuesta correcta, debo crear un for anidado?.

Mi código lo tengo así

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Validar__mail2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean arroba = false;

    boolean punto = false;

    String mail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su email por favor: ");

    for (int i = 0; i<mail.length(); i++) {

        if(mail.charAt(i)=='@' && mail.charAt(i)=='.') {

            arroba = true;
            punto = true;
        }

    }

    if (arroba == true && punto == true) {

        System.out.println("El mail ingresado es correcto");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("El mail ingresado es incorrecto");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Estás validando que un char sea, a la vez, una arroba y un punto: `mail.charAt(i)=='@' && mail.charAt(i)=='.'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más adecuado es usar una expresión regular, ya que no se trata únicamente de validar la existencia de "." y "@" si no su posición dentro de la dirección e-mail, en este caso la expresión regular sería:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$
```

Puedes implementarla en un método:

```
public static boolean isValid(String email) { 
        String emailREGEX = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$";                               
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailREGEX ); 
        if (email == null){ 
            return false; 
        }
        return pattern .matcher(email).matches(); 
    }
```

Este sería un ejemplo de validación de cadenas e-mail :

```
"jorgesys@tototita.com"   true
"jorgesys@tototitacom"    false
"jorgesystototita.com"    false
"@jorgesystototita.com"   false
".jorgesystototita@com"   false
```

todas las comprobaciones se realizaron correctamente en cambio si usas el método que propones, tendría algunas inconsistencias:

```
"jorgesys@tototita.com"   true
"jorgesys@tototitacom"    false
"jorgesystototita.com"    false
"@jorgesystototita.com"   true    //Dirección no válida!
".jorgesystototita@com"   true    //Dirección no válida!
```

Answer (score 1):

La clase String tiene el método matches, que evalúa si **toda** la cadena cumple con la expresión regular:

```
if( mail.matches(".+@.+\\..+") )
   System.out.println("El mail ingresado es correcto");
else
   System.out.println("El mail ingresado es incorrecto");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude identificar el problema, efectivamente faltaba añadir un for el cual me recorrería la cadena de String y validara el punto(.)

El código quedo así:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Validar__mail2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean arroba = false;

    boolean punto = false;

    String mail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su email por favor: ");

    for (int i = 0; i<mail.length(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j<mail.length(); j++) {

            if(mail.charAt(i)=='@' && mail.charAt(j)=='.') {

                arroba = true;
                punto = true;
            }

        }

    }

    if (arroba == true && punto == true) {

        System.out.println("El mail ingresado es correcto");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("El mail ingresado es incorrecto");
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: Seguro puedes usar una forma más rápida que con dos for anidados. Vas a recorrer la cadena del email N^2 veces, arrancando cada vez un poco más adelante. Podrías hacer un if-else con un solo for y, si el caracter es arroba, pones true en una variable; si es punto, pones true en la otra; si no es ninguna de esas, no haces nada y siguen en false... si te da más curiosidad, puedes usar una expresión regular y así es aún más rápida la revisión. Saludos!

Comment: Definitivamente lo más adecuado es el uso de una REGEX como coment a Alfabravo @YazinCastañoMoreno , ya que por ejemplo las direcciones "@Yazindominio.com" y ".Yazindominio@com" las consideraría correctas aúnque en realidad no lo son.